# How does ubuntu charge the batteries in a laptop if there are two of them?

Tags: 17.10, power-management, laptop, hardware, battery

I am total beginner, I just switched to Ubuntu 17.10, so I do not really understand it.

I was fiddling around when I noticed that, when I plug in the power cable, both of my batteries in my lenovo x270 were charging simultaneously. I remember when I had windows 10, the batteries would first charge one to 80% then charge the other to 100% and then top up the the first one to 100%.

I am worried that I may be damaging the batteries, and the only reason that I got this ultrabook is its batterylife.

Thank you for your understanding!

Jurgen

P.S: I also wanted to know if I should expect the battery to last more or less now that I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: AFAIK, how the batteries charge is determined by the electronic design, and maybe something in the BIOS. Ubuntu just shows what the charge is.

Comment: I have owned numerous Lenovo ThinkPad T400 series laptops with dual batteries (I'm currently using a T470p with two batteries), and Linux has never damaged my batteries. I have no idea in what order it charges my batteries - I've never given it a second thought (although I'll probably have a quick look now).

Comment: I will try to run the battery down completely and charge it to full to see what happens.

Comment: I would assume since a battery charges WITHOUT an OS present (ie. you can remove the harddisk and still have the batteries charging) that this should be independent of the operating system and software to control this is merely something to set BIOS options?  Maybe there is a setting in BIOS that does set this? In Linux TLP is software to manage this https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681

Comment: Sometimes when I charge it goes to 100% and sometimes it stops at 99%. Maybe it is like that to prevent overcharging the battery.

Comment: I have the impression that Ubuntu will discharge my first battery until it is at about 5% and then start using the second battery. Thus the first battery is often low and gets some damages. A friend of mine has got the same computer but uses Windows and does not experience that problem.